# what is best error log file extension for both Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, logging, extension-methods, error-log

What is the best extension for error log ?
`.txt` or `.log` or `no extension` ? is there any problem if i use `log` extension in linux and windows ?

Comment: What criteria do you use to decide whether a particular extension is "better"?

Comment: prevent from public access and traditional way and supporting extension for all OS @YePhIcK

Comment: Public access is **not** controlled by extensions but by file access permissions. As for "supporting extensions for all OS" - I'm afraid you are confusing *OS* and *application* support here.

Comment: Agree with your points. i will go with `.log`